# Missing adverb in a phrase?

Tags: ellipsis

The following sentence comes from the English translation of Andrzej Sapkowski's "The Tower Of The Swallow":

> The length and breadth of the world, all royal couples had separate bed chambers.

Would this be grammaticaly correct or is it missing an adverb as in:

> **Across** the length and breadth of the world, all royal couples had separate bed chambers.

Or:

> **Throughout** the length and breadth of the world, all royal couples had separate bed chambers.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The preposition won't improve the poorly expressed idea. I am not sure that criticizing translations is our best skill here. Across the entire world, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion is the best way to understand it; yes, a preposition like that is implied. Omitting it is a bit unusual in this case, with such a lengthy phrase, but it's similar to the phrase ["the world over"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/the-world-over), as in "The world over, humans smile to express pleasure."